# Issues with placement of Javascript promise

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am I doing wrong with the placement of this promise?

I need all the elements of the first function to complete before the second function gets triggered.

Thanks in advance.

Function 1:

```
var promise1 = $("#button-1").on('click', async new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  csInterface.evalScript("Duplicate()");
  await SafeMode();
  csInterface.evalScript("FlattenImage()");
  await SafeMode();
  csInterface.evalScript("ConverttosRGB()");
  await SafeMode();
  csInterface.evalScript("Resolution300PPI()");
  await SafeMode();
  csInterface.evalScript("SetBackgroundtoLayer()");
  await SafeMode();
  csInterface.evalScript("Postcard1()");
  resolve();
}));
```

Function 2:

```
promise1.then(function() {

// next function here

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

promise1 is not a promise and is actually a jQuery object. Make a function that will generate the promise you require (see below).

```js
const promise1 =() => new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {

  /** Commented so you can see that it works
  csInterface.evalScript("Duplicate()");
  await SafeMode();
  csInterface.evalScript("FlattenImage()");
  await SafeMode();
  csInterface.evalScript("ConverttosRGB()");
  await SafeMode();
  csInterface.evalScript("Resolution300PPI()");
  await SafeMode();
  csInterface.evalScript("SetBackgroundtoLayer()");
  await SafeMode();
  csInterface.evalScript("Postcard1()");*/
  
  //Adding time
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("promise1");
    resolve();
  }, 500);
  
})

$("#button-1").on('click', () => {
  promise1().then(() => {
    //next bit of your code here
    console.log("next");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-1">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Having `async () => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { /*.... */ })` does not make to much sense. You do not use `await` in the arrow function anywhere, and directly return a new Promise, so you can omit the `async`. If there is an async in front of it you have the expectation that somewhere a relevant await appears.

Comment: I looked closely at the code and  the `await` statements you commented out are within the `function(resolve, reject) { ... }` callback of the Promise you created, and this function is not marked as `async` so the statements with `await` will result in a syntax error when you remove the comments. You code should be `const promise1 = () => new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {`

Comment: Yes, fixed it while you were typing

Comment: That worked brilliantly, thank you!
Just to clarify, the async and await script featured in the first function is there for a reason totally separate to my attempts to get the promise working, but I wanted to include it in the question in case it was part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`on()` function will not return a promise, you need to declare your async function before, call it in as your callback and chain it with your THEN.

Also, async function will automatically return a Promise, no need to built it yourself.

```js
const resolveAfter1Seconds = function(id) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("resolution " + id);
    }, 1000);
  });
};

const callback = async function() {

  console.log("in callback", "start");
  
  let res = await resolveAfter1Seconds(1);
  console.log("in callback 1", res);
  res = await resolveAfter1Seconds(2);
  console.log("in callback 2", res);
  res = await resolveAfter1Seconds(3);
  console.log("in callback 3", res);
  
  return "what you want your promise to finally return";
};


$("#button-1").on('click', () => {
  callback().then(x => console.log("THEN", x))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button-1">Click me!</button>
```